# CK Editor 5: Mix Multiple Editable And Read-Only Paragraphs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

Using CK Editor 5 for the first time this week. I've already spent hours googling this, reading the CKE docs, looking at similar questions here on SO. Found some solutions close to what I want, but none so far that fit my use case.

Within a single instance of CKE, can I have both editable and read-only paragraphs? For example, let's say a document consists of 5 paragraphs. I want the odd paragraphs (1, 3, 5) to be editable, and the even paragraphs (2, 4) to be read-only.

Not looking for a solution that involves toggling edit/read-only on a click event. Looking to have this set up initially, so users are restricted by default to only editing certain paragraphs, and cannot change those settings.

Can this be done within a single instance of CKE? If yes, how? Are there any examples of this on line? Thanks ahead of time for any guidance that can be provided!

Comment: This is a interesting use case. But there traps here. If eg. Paragraph 1 is editable but 2 no and user erases paragraph 1 so paragraph 2 will promoted do fisrt and will be editable? Or will have fixed placeholders to keep editable places?

Comment: @Aloiso: Good point. There would have to be some kind of  "fixed placeholders to keep editable places." Maybe the read-only chunks could have a 'data-editable' Boolean attribute that CKE could hook into? The specific details of how to make this work is  what my question is all about.